# Verbs after "In case"

Tags: tense, phrases, conjunctions

As a grammar hint, it is stated under the entry for "**In case**" within Longman Dictionary of Contemporary that we have to use **simple present/past** or **should** after in case, for example:

> They locked themselves in their houses in case there was more trouble.

But do we have to use these tenses for all verbs in the clause which starts with ***in case***? For example is the following statement correct grammatically?

> You should back up your data in case there is a problem which will lead to a data loss.

Or should we write it as follows?

> You should back up your data in case there is a problem which leads to a data loss.

Comment: Longman's definition applies to *in case there **is** a problem*. It makes no difference what tense you use for any further text modifying the noun ***problem*** there. It could be a problem *that would have been insoluble a century ago*, or a problem *that no-one has ever seen before*, or a problem *that will not be resolved in my lifetime*, for example.

Answer (score -1):

> You should back up your data in case there is a problem which will lead to a data loss.

This is not correct. "In case" always refers to a *hypothetical* situation. The modal verb "will" indicates *certainty*. I would assume the above sentence was wrong, but taken at face value it could be assumed that the final clause refers back to the backing up of data and that the middle of the sentence is a parenthetical clause, for example:

> You should back up your data (in case there is a problem) which will lead to a data loss.

This, of course, wouldn't make sense.

So you are correct - almost - with your re-write. It should be written as:

> You should back up your data in case there is a problem **that** leads to a data loss.

'That' should be used for *defining clauses*. As you are defining a particular kind of problem, use 'that', not 'which'.